# Improving MVC 4 DropDownList

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently populating my drop downlists like this...

```
  public  List<NewLogin> GetRolesForDDL()
    {
        using (database db = new database())
        {
            return (from r in db.UserRole
                    select new NewLogin
                    {
                        UserRole = r.Role,
                        RoleID = r.RoleID
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }    
    public  NewLogin RoleDDL()
    {
        NewLogin nl = new NewLogin();
        using (database db = new database())
        {                               // populates ddl
            nl.RoleList = new SelectList(GetRolesForDDL(), "RoleID", "UserRole");                
        }
        return nl;
    }
```

The part I don't like in particular is where `nl.RoleList = new SelectList(GetRolesForDDL()`
Is there a better way I can do this, by keeping within the same style and bypassing that method and using a quick and easy lambda expression instead?

Also another quick question is...

`@Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.RoleID, Model.RoleList)`
When I pass this to the controller I get the RoleID value, but my RoleName(text of ddl)
get's passed as null. Can I access both RoleName and ID without fetching it in the backend?

I know this doesn't work, but I'm thinking it would have to be something like

`DDLFor(u => u.RoleID, u.RoleName)`

Comment: Is there code missing?  Why are you making a database connection twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I access both RoleName and ID without fetching it in the backend?

Yes, I believe so if you want to write a bit of javascript.  You would need to create a 
hidden field and on every select list change event set the value of that field.

Something like

```
$(body).on("change", "#selectbox", function() {
    $("#inputbox").val($(this).val());
});
```

I'm also unsure as to why you are creating the database connection twice but I would consider
passing that into the GetRoles method like so:

```
public  IEnumerable<NewLogin> GetRolesForDDL(database db)
{
    return (from r in db.UserRole
            select new NewLogin
            {
                UserRole = r.Role,
                RoleID = r.RoleID
            });     
}    
public  NewLogin RoleDDL()
{
    using (database db = new database())
    {                               
        var roles = GetRolesForDDL(db).ToList();
        // populates ddl
        return new NewLogin
        {
            RoleList = new SelectList(roles, "RoleID", "UserRole");                
        }
    }
}
```

Or even if both of these methods are part of a class consider passing the database into the class constructor and using it as a private instance variable.

Comment: thats pointing that out about multiple db connections, it's unnecessary